# Confused how the substitution expresses this recurrence

Tags: recurrence-relations

Consider the recurrence $a_n = a_{n-1}(1 - a_{n-1})$ for $n > 0$ with $a_0 = \frac{1}{2}$. Since the terms in the recurrence decrease and are positive, it is not hard to see that $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n = 0$. To find the speed of convergence, it is natural to consider $1/a_n$. Substituting, we have $\frac{1}{a_n} = \frac{1}{a_{n-1}}(\frac{1}{1-a_{n-1}}) = \frac{1}{a_{n-1}}(1+a_{n-1}+a_{n-1}^2+\cdots) > \frac{1}{a_{n-1}} + 1$.

I don't understand how to get $ \frac{1}{a_{n-1}}(\frac{1}{1-a_{n-1}}) = \frac{1}{a_{n-1}}(1+a_{n-1}+a_{n-1}^2+\cdots)$. I think it was by factoring but can't seem simplify to that expression. Would anyone please show me how it happened?

Comment: The power series $\frac 1{1-x} = 1 + x + x^2 + x^3 + \dots$ converges when $|x|<1$. You may recognise it as the sum of an infinite geometric series.

Comment: Why not use $$\frac1{a_n}=\frac1{a_{n-1}}+\frac1{1-a_{n-1}}>\frac1{a_{n-1}}+1?$$

Comment: @ProfessorVector How does $\frac{1}{a_{n-1}} + \frac{1}{1-a_{n-1}} = \frac{1}{a_n}$?

Comment: @randomvalue Add the two fractions by using the common denominator $a_{n-1}(1-a_{n-1})=a_n$.

Comment: Came from your other question. This statement is in the first sentence of your question.

Answer (score 1):

That is just the geometric series. As you state, $a_n$ decreases (and starts out at $1/2$), so the expansion (valid for $\lvert a_n \rvert < 1$) works:

$\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{1 - a_n}
  &= 1 + a_n + a_n^2 + \dotsb \\
  &= \sum_{k \ge 0} a_n^k
\end{align*}$